# AngularFireAuth.user observable won't emit when placed in withLatestFrom RxJS operator

Tags: angular, rxjs, firebase-authentication, angularfire

The `AngularFireAuth.user` observable works fine if it is the source observable e.g.

```js
this.AngularFireAuth.user.subscribe((u) => console.log(u))
```

but blocks my observable stream if I place it in the `withLatestFrom` operator, e.g.

```js
of("test")
.pipe(
   tap(console.log), // log showing up
   withLatestFrom(this.AngularFireAuth.user),
   tap(console.log)  // log not showing up
   ).subscribe()
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I get around it? I need the current auth state but the source observable needs to be a different observable than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is because user stream didn't emit anything yet. I believe the easiest case to fix this problem would be to add `startsWith(null)` for the user stream

```
withLatestFrom(this.AngularFireAuth.user.pipe(startsWith(null)))
```

Comment: This works ! However, I don't understand why the stream doesn't just wait for the user observable to emit a first value before continuing, instead of just blocking.

Comment: that is `withLatestFrom`'s operator's and `of` behavior. of emits value just as the subscription is issued. and withLatestFrom skips source events untill the first one of the pased observable

Answer (score 0):

The observable `AngularFireAuth.user` probably has no emition during the usage of `withLatestfrom()`.
You could use the `combineLatest` operator. The operator emit latest values when one of the passed observables emit. In your case this is the `AngularFireAuth.user` observable.

```
of("test")
.pipe(
   tap(console.log), // log showing up
   combineLatest(this.AngularFireAuth.user),
   tap(console.log)  // log not showing up
   ).subscribe()
```

[combineLatest documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest)

> Combines multiple Observables to create an Observable whose values are
> calculated from the latest values of each of its input Observables.

Comment: This would make the user observable a source observable (i.e. the stream would emit every time the user observable emits), however, I just want to get a snapshot of its current value.